# Sorting with constraints

Tags: python

I have a list:

```
l = ['dylan', 'andy', 'alan', 'bob', 'but this must go last']
```

Is there any pythonic way to sort the items in alphabetical order with some constraints? I want a specific item to be the last one, so that result, after sorting is not:

```
l.sort()
['alan', 'andy', 'bob', 'but this must go last', 'dylan']
```

but rather:

```
['alan', 'andy', 'bob', 'dylan', 'but this must go last']
```

The solution that comes to my mind is to remove specific item from the list, sort it and then put it at the end. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why is this needed?

Comment: constraints are only this type - putting specific elements in the list end? or there can be other variations as well?

Comment: This is the only type of constrain. The reason I need this is as follows: I have some plots/results which I want to present in alphabetical order, but since I have one very specific case, I want it to be at the end.

Comment: @DanD. why deleting your okay answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just get rid of the last element when sorting and afterwards put it at the end like this:

```
 sorted(l[:-1]) + [l[-1]]
```

Or, more generally, if you want to exclude the i-th element:

```
 sorted(l[:i]+l[i:]) + [l[i]]
```

Comment: That's what I had in mind, but the way you solve it is more elegant than mine with a two-liner involving append. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't over-think it. Remove the item that should be last from the list, sort the list and add the removed item to the list's end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more general solution, I think you must implement your own custom list class and override compare methods like they do on http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-sort-a-list-tuple-or-object-with-sorted-in-python/

Another different approach is create a list without the element which is going to the end, sort that new list and append the ripped element.

Something like:

```
new_list = sorted([item for item in l if item != 'but this must go last'])
new_list.append('but this must go last')
```